# Yarn cannot find module (html-to-text)

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I ran `yarn add html-to-text` successfully. The package is in the `package.json` list. Now when I try to require the module as described in the manual, it says `Error: Cannot find module html-to-text`. The same repository is working on another laptop (Mac). I am using Windows, but I don't believe that should be the issue.

```
const { convert } = require('html-to-text');
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

It looks like it is with other new modules too! Running `yarn` adds it to `node_modules`, but it says `Module not found` on `import`

Comment: Can you try using `npm` instead?

Comment: `npm install` crashed with many errors, starting with `path node_modules/sharp`. `Command failed`. And then many more

Comment: So, are you using `import` or `require`? Share your `package.json` and any other config files. I managed to create a simple project using yarn with just `"html-to-text": "^8.1.0"` in my package.json dependencies, a single `index.js` file with `const { convert } = require("html-to-text");`. I ran `node index.js` from the command line and couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: Found the solution. I needed to run `yarn docker --build` and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run `yarn docker --build` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it

**npm install html-to-text**

And then use

const { convert } = require('html-to-text');

It might be helpful for you